# Creating local table in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm trying to do a local table in **MudBlazor**, that has elements from two **JSON** gets. This is example code. The IEnumerable Elements is given to Table as a source.

```
private IEnumerable<MyClass> Elements = new List<MyClass>();


protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await this.SetTable();
}

private async Task SetTable()
{

    this._loading = true;
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    var data = await this.Api.Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Model>();
    var data2 = await this.Api.Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Model2>();  (data and data2 is loaded correctly)
    
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count(), i++) 
    {
        Elements.ElementAt(i).Id = data.ElementAt(i).Id;
        Elements.ElementAt(i).Name = data2.ElementAt(i).Name;
    }
    
    this._loading = false;
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged); 
}
```

Class MyClass:

```
namespace XY
{
  public class MyClass
 {
    public MyClass()
    {
                        
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }  
  }
 }
```

But it returns error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
```

Is it something with initialization? Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that both sizes of `data` and `data2` are equal each other, you should use `Add` method of `List` class instead in the `for loop`.

```
Elements.Add(new MyClass{Id = data.ElementAt(i), Name = data2.ElementAt(i)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `List<MyClass> Elements` is initialized, but never has any instances of `MyClass` added to it.  When you try to use an index on a collection with 0 items, it will throw that error.

If you can provide your `Model` and `Model2` classes, then I can show exactly how I would do it.

@snr has it right, but personally, I don't like using indexing-- partly because of the possibility of an out of bounds error.  That presumably is why they asked if you can guarantee that your two datasets will be the same size.

I'd prefer to use a `foreach` loop to iterate once dataset, and match records in the other with Linq.